# If the semantic entailment relation u ⊨ v holds, is u ⊢ v valid?

Tags: logic

I am preparing for exam and am struggling the concepts of semantic entailment and validity.

I understand that if `u ⊢ v` is valid ( it is a tautology) the semantic entailment relation `u ⊨ v` will hold because if all values of u is True v will by necessity also be True, since it is valid.

Does the converse hold though? If the semantic entailment relation `u ⊨ v` hold is `u ⊢ v` valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to fix your symbolism : **u ⊢ v** means that **v** is *derivable* from *u* in the proof system of e.g. *propositional calculus*, while **u ⊨ v** means that **u** *entails* **v**, i.e. (as you say) whenever **u** is TRUE, **v** will by necessity also be TRUE.

Having said that, we have that :

> if **u ⊨ v**, then **u ⊢ v**, by the [Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) of the propositional calculus.

---

A linked but different question is the following :

> we have that **u ⊨ v** in classical propositional calculus iff **u → v** is a *tautology* (i.e. it is *valid*).

The proof is simple :

*(i)* if **u → v** is a *tautology*, then the case **u** TRUE and **v** FALSE is ruled out; thus : **u ⊨ v**.

*(ii)* if **u ⊨ v**, this means that the case **u** TRUE and **v** FALSE is ruled out; thus : **u → v** is a *tautology*.

Comment: I copied the the symbolism from the textbook... The example is overly simplified though. In the textbook it was φ1,φ2,φ3 ... ⊢ ψ